# iOS 10 Rich Media Push Notification videos and audios are not working in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios10, unusernotificationcenter

I am adding Media in iOS 10 Push notification but only images are working in push, videos and audios not working in it. How to do that in Objective-C ? My Code is as follows:

**AppDelegate.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate,UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@end
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    if(SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN( @"10.0" )) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    } else{
        UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
        center.delegate = self;
        [center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge) completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error)
        {
            if( !error ) {
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
                // required to get the app to do anything at all about push notifications
                NSLog( @"Push registration success." );
            } else {
                NSLog( @"Push registration FAILED" );
                NSLog( @"ERROR: %@ - %@", error.localizedFailureReason, error.localizedDescription );
                NSLog( @"SUGGESTIONS: %@ - %@", error.localizedRecoveryOptions, error.localizedRecoverySuggestion );
            }
        }];
    }
}

-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    NSString * token = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", deviceToken];
    //Format token as per need:
    token = [token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    token = [token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""];
    token = [token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""];
     NSLog(@"Device Token is \n%@",token);
}

-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Error:%@",error);
}

-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO( @"10.0" )) {
        [self application:application didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:^(UIBackgroundFetchResult result){}];
    } else {
        /// previous stuffs for iOS 9 and below. I've shown an alert wth received data.
    }
}

-(void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void(^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
    // iOS 10 will handle notifications through other methods

    if( NOTIFY_VISITORS_SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO( @"10.0" ) )
    {
        NSLog( @"iOS version >= 10. Let NotificationCenter handle this one." );
        // set a member variable to tell the new delegate that this is background
        return;
    }
    NSLog( @"HANDLE PUSH, didReceiveRemoteNotification: %@", userInfo );
    // custom code to handle notification content
    if( [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive )
    {
        NSLog( @"INACTIVE" );
        completionHandler( UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData );
    }
    else if( [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground )
    {  
        NSLog( @"BACKGROUND" );  
        completionHandler( UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData );  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        NSLog( @"FOREGROUND" );  
        completionHandler( UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData );  
    }  
}

- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler {
    NSLog( @"Handle push from foreground" );
    // custom code to handle push while app is in the foreground
    NSLog(@"%@", notification.request.content.userInfo);
}

- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler {
    NSLog( @"Handle push from background or closed" );
    // if you set a member variable in didReceiveRemoteNotification, you  will know if this is from closed or background
    NSLog(@"%@", response.notification.request.content.userInfo);
```

Then I've added a new target **Notification Service Extension** as following:

**NotificationService.h**

```
#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>
@interface NotificationService : UNNotificationServiceExtension
@end
```

**NotificationService.m**

```
#import "NotificationService.h"

@interface NotificationService ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) void (^contentHandler)(UNNotificationContent *contentToDeliver);
@property (nonatomic, strong) UNMutableNotificationContent *bestAttemptContent;

@end

@implementation NotificationService

- (void)didReceiveNotificationRequest:(UNNotificationRequest *)request withContentHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationContent * _Nonnull))contentHandler {
    self.contentHandler = contentHandler;
    self.bestAttemptContent = [request.content mutableCopy];

    // Modify the notification content here...
    //self.bestAttemptContent.body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ [modified]", self.bestAttemptContent.body];

    // check for media attachment, example here uses custom payload keys mediaUrl and mediaType
    NSDictionary *userInfo = request.content.userInfo;
    if (userInfo == nil) {
        [self contentComplete];
        return;
    }

    NSString *mediaUrl = userInfo[@"mediaUrl"];
    NSString *mediaType = userInfo[@"mediaType"];

    if (mediaUrl == nil || mediaType == nil) {
        [self contentComplete];
        return;
    }

    // load the attachment
    [self loadAttachmentForUrlString:mediaUrl
                            withType:mediaType
                   completionHandler:^(UNNotificationAttachment *attachment) {
                       if (attachment) {
                           self.bestAttemptContent.attachments = [NSArray arrayWithObject:attachment];
                       }
                       [self contentComplete];
                   }];

}

- (void)serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire {
    // Called just before the extension will be terminated by the system.
    // Use this as an opportunity to deliver your "best attempt" at modified content, otherwise the original push payload will be used.
    [self contentComplete];
}

- (void)contentComplete {
    self.contentHandler(self.bestAttemptContent);
}

- (NSString *)fileExtensionForMediaType:(NSString *)type {
    NSString *ext = type;

    if ([type isEqualToString:@"image"]) {
        ext = @"jpg";
    }

    if ([type isEqualToString:@"video"]) {
        ext = @"mp4";
    }

    if ([type isEqualToString:@"audio"]) {
        ext = @"mp3";
    }

    return [@"." stringByAppendingString:ext];
}

- (void)loadAttachmentForUrlString:(NSString *)urlString withType:(NSString *)type completionHandler:(void(^)(UNNotificationAttachment *))completionHandler  {

    __block UNNotificationAttachment *attachment = nil;
    NSURL *attachmentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSString *fileExt = [self fileExtensionForMediaType:type];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
    [[session downloadTaskWithURL:attachmentURL
                completionHandler:^(NSURL *temporaryFileLocation, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                    if (error != nil) {
                        NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
                    } else {
                        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
                        NSURL *localURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[temporaryFileLocation.path stringByAppendingString:fileExt]];
                        [fileManager moveItemAtURL:temporaryFileLocation toURL:localURL error:&error];

                        NSError *attachmentError = nil;
                        attachment = [UNNotificationAttachment attachmentWithIdentifier:@"" URL:localURL options:nil error:&attachmentError];
                        if (attachmentError) {
                        NSLog(@"%@", attachmentError.localizedDescription);
                        }
                    }
                    completionHandler(attachment);
                }] resume];
}
@end
```

and my Notification Service Extension **Info.plist** is:
[image: Notification Service Extension Info.plist]

And I'm using php Script to send push notification as follows:

**TestPush.php**

```
 <?php

    // Put your device token here (without spaces):
      $deviceToken = 'my device tocken goes here';
    // Put your private key's passphrase here:
    $passphrase = 'mypassphase';
    // Put your alert message here:
    $message = 'Test iOS 10 Media Attachment Push';

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    $ctx = stream_context_create();
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'cafile', 'entrust_2048_ca.cer');

    // Open a connection to the APNS server
    $fp = stream_socket_client(
        'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
        $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

    if (!$fp)
        exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

    echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

    // Create the payload body
   $body = array(
  'aps' => array(
    'alert' => 'Rich notification',
    'sound' => 'default',
    'mutable-content' => 1
  ),
  'mediaUrl'  => 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2a/FloorGoban.JPG/1024px-FloorGoban.JPG',
  'mediaType' => 'image'
);
    // Encode the payload as JSON
    $payload = json_encode($body);

    // Build the binary notification
    $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

    // Send it to the server
    $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

    if (!$result)
        echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
    else
        echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

    // Close the connection to the server
    fclose($fp);
```

JPG,PNG,GIF images are working fine with this code but Videos and Audios are not working although images,video and audio are hosted on `https://` server.

Can anyone help me please.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem than you and I solve it using the correct extensions for the media to attach, take a look to this link https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unnotificationattachment and try to use mp4 for example for a video. Hope it was useful